# How to get $((u \cdot \nabla v), v)) = 0$

Tags: integration, fluid-dynamics

I'm reading on weak formulations with navier stokes equation, and I read from a paper saying the following,

---

$((u \cdot \nabla v), v)) = 0$
which shows in particular that the nonlinear term makes no contribution to the kinetic energy.
(This equality is easy to check using an integration by parts).

---

I could not figure out how to show the results with integration by parts.

Comment: does $(a,b)$ denote the inner product here? I've only ever seen $\langle a,b\rangle$

Comment: Yes, (a, b) denotes inner product.

Comment: In which case I don't understand - you're taking the inner product of a scalar with a vector/function, since $u\cdot\nabla v$ would product just a single value...

Comment: Unless taking the inner product of a scalar with a vector/function is what you want?

Comment: Is the "$\cdot$" a dot product? Or is it another inner product

Comment: I should make it clearer that both u, v are vectors in d=2 or 3, so $u \cdot \nabla v$ is still a vector. I think it is $(u\cdot \nabla v_x, u\cdot \nabla v_y)$.